# How can I access a function in a JavaScript Array only with a String?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So, I'm currently trying to get into emulator programming and I chose JavaScript because it's the language I'm fully fluent in.

Basically my Problem boils down to this:
I have an Array which is my Opcode Table, thus it binds my functions to a number.

E. g.:

```
function function_one() {
  alert("hello");
}

function function_two() {
  alert("World")
}

var optable = [
        function_one,
        function_two
];

optable[0](); //runs function_one()
optable[1](); //runs function_two();
```

Now, I want to write a simple and primitive compiler which takes part of the assembly code line, searches for the first string in this array and returns the index of the function inside the optable, but everything I tried just returns `NaN`. The currentLine[] is encoded like this:
["function_one", "foo", "bar"] (As strings, yeah)

E.g.:

```
var currentLine = byLine[i].split(" ");
        console.log(currentLine[0]);
        currentProgram += optable.findIndex(currentLine[0]); //<-- NaN
        console.log(currentProgram);
```

I understand that this is not how this works because the optable array holds functions and I search for a string, but how can I get this to work? I got something to work with eval(), but I can already see where this could be leading... (Security etc.)

Comment: On your 0th index it is function keyword and not name of the function. Function name is at index 1 (after doing split)

Comment: Oh, wait, maybe this part wasn't clear enough, will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `object[propertyName]` notation:

```js
const optable = {
  function_one : ()=>console.log("Hello"),
  function_two : ()=>console.log("world!"),
};

stringContainingAFunctionName = "function_one";
optable[stringContainingAFunctionName]();
```

Comment: I guess it might be the best to use properties. Thanks! Btw, thus works

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Eval()` function to evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string however it's not recommended to use in production

e.g `eval(optable[0]())`

Comment: Should never use eval, not recommended.

Comment: `eval` is [evil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)

Comment: I already tried it, but the problem is that if someone would smuggle in an Opcodeliteral named length or __proto__, it would return the wrong result